# Spring Animations on WindowManager View

Tags: android, android-animation, android-windowmanager

*First off, if you're taking time to handle this massive problem I've been having, thank you! Various forms of this question have been asked on SO, but I have yet to find one that deals with the same bug I have today.*

TLDR; [My icon disappears](https://photos.app.goo.gl/AIV92lLreQZrq33F3)

I, like many others, have created a floating chat head. I tried to animate it using the DynamicAnimation library in the Android SDK, but the view begins to disappear when the animations begins.

Declaration and instantiation of mFloatingView:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
params.x = 0
params.y = 0;

mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);
```

In the following case I move my view to the current touch location:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    //Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the view.
    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);


    //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingView, params);
    return true;
```

Then, when I lift my finger it animates the view to the nearest edge with the following animation:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

    SpringAnimation animationX = new SpringAnimation(mFloatingView, SpringAnimation.X);

    SpringForce springForce = new SpringForce(desinationXValue);
    springForce.setStiffness(SpringForce.STIFFNESS_LOW);
    springForce.setDampingRatio(SpringForce.DAMPING_RATIO_NO_BOUNCY);

    animation.setSpring(springForce);

    animationX.addUpdateListener(new DynamicAnimation.OnAnimationUpdateListener() {

        public void onAnimationUpdate(DynamicAnimation dynamicAnimation, float value, float velocity) {
            params.x = (int) value;

            // IMPORTANT CODE
            mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingView, params);
        }
    });
    return true;
```

Using the above code, when I move the icon around, the view is visible using `updateViewLayout(mFloatingView, params)`. When I release it and begin the animation, the icon animates, but the root of the view stays in place, so the icon is only visible in it's original corner.

Why would `updateViewLayout(mFloatingView, params)` work to move the root of the view in the `ACTION_MOVE` case, but not with each frame of the animation in `onAnimationUpdate`?

For clarity I've included a [video of the issue.](https://photos.app.goo.gl/AIV92lLreQZrq33F3) Notice the icon is visible when pulled from the original corner, but not when pulled from an invisible corner.

Comment: Yeah that worked like a charm, thanks so much! Can you explain why that worked in an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I have the same problem and can't figure it out :(

Comment: The comment that helped me was deleted unfortunately. If I remember corectly, I moved the SpringAnimation into a new class I called SpringListener which implemented the animation update listener. So in my floatingview service, I setOnTouchListener on my mFloatingView to a new instance of the SpringListener which would handle all the animation update code. Moving all the animation code to the other class solved the problem for reasons still unknown to me

Comment: @BenGraham I also having the same problem can you provide me some code

Comment: @BenGraham please update your answer because many people getting the same issue, I almost spend a week and did not find any solution

Comment: This is the Answer https://github.com/recruit-lifestyle/FloatingView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/jp/co/recruit_lifestyle/android/floatingview/FloatingView.java

Answer (score 1):

Convert this

```
SpringAnimation animationX = new SpringAnimation(mFloatingView, SpringAnimation.X);
```

to

```
SpringAnimation animationX = new SpringAnimation(new FloatValueHolder());
```